# get only the date of last command in Linux (fromt the last login)

Tags: linux

last command in linux shows the last logins in the system.

Is there any script that I can retrive only the date of the these last logins?

thanks

Comment: ask this on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Quick n dirty

```
$ last | grep -v "system boot" | awk '{for (i=4; i<NF; i++) printf $i " "; print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
last | {m,g}awk 'gsub(/\t/, " ", $!(NF *= /system boot/))^_ * NF' \
                 FS='^[ \t]*[^ \t]*[ \t]+[^ \t]*[ \t]+[^ \t]*[ \t]+' OFS=
```

I only have `macos ~ (BSD 4.4)` and not `Linux` here so I can't test the output of it (even the `last` command looks different here). Let me know if this works or not.

If you don't care for that final `gsub()` bit that's more nice to have than essential, then the body is even simpler :

```
{m,g}awk 'NF *= /system boot/' { FS=... OFS=... }
```